# Updating Track ordering within playlist

Tags: javascript, html, soundcloud

I would like to change the order of the Tracks associated with a playlist.

I am using Soundcloud javascript API - "`SC.put()`" to send playlist object with updated `tracks` array, with desired order, to resource `/playlists/{id}` uri. Even after the api call the `tracks` array has the same ordering.

Unless my assumption, that order of `track` objects in the array, is the play order for that playlist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By inspecting the how sound cloud website adds tracks to a playlist/set. I have found my solution.

The data being `PUT` to Soundcloud's playlist-end point (`/playlists/{id}`) must look like:

```
{
  playlist : {  
    tracks: [{ id: 11 }, { id: 22 }, { id: 33}]
  }
}
```

Order of the objects within `tracks` array would be persisted as well.